# Connect to Amazon account using Scala

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, amazon-s3

I want to connect to my Amazon account in order to delete resources inside my s3 storage.

I have the access key and secret key, and this is how I started to build my connection to Amazon:

```
def connectToAmaozn(): Unit = {
  val AWS_ACCESS_KEY=conf.getString("WebRecorder.PushSession.AccessKey")
  val AWS_SECRET_KEY=conf.getString("WebRecorder.PushSession.SecretKey")

  val AWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY,AWS_SECRET_KEY)

}
```

Can you elaborate on how I may do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this solution to get bucket name and number of objects:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import com.amazonaws.auth.{AWSStaticCredentialsProvider, BasicAWSCredentials}
import com.amazonaws.services.s3
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.{GetObjectTaggingRequest, ObjectListing, S3ObjectSummary}
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.{AmazonS3Client, AmazonS3ClientBuilder}
import com.clicktale.pipeline.framework.dal.ConfigParser.conf
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model._

import scala.language.postfixOps

class Amazon {

  val AWS_ACCESS_KEY = conf.getString("WebRecorder.PushSession.AccessKey")
  val AWS_SECRET_KEY = conf.getString("WebRecorder.PushSession.SecretKey")
  val bucketName = "nv-q-s3-assets-01"
  val provider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY))
  val client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(provider).withRegion("us-east-1").build()
//  def connectToAmazon(): Unit = {
//
//    val provider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY))
//    val client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(provider).withRegion("us-east-1").build()

  def removeObjectsFromBucket(){

    println("Removing objects from bucket...")
      var object_listing: ObjectListing = client.listObjects(bucketName)
      var flag: Boolean = true
      while (flag) {
        val iterator: Iterator[_] = object_listing.getObjectSummaries.iterator()
        while (iterator.hasNext) {
          val summary: S3ObjectSummary = iterator.next().asInstanceOf[S3ObjectSummary]
          client.deleteObject(bucketName, summary.getKey())
        }

        flag=false

      }

    }

  def countNumberOfObjectsInsideBucket(): Unit ={

    var object_listing: ObjectListing = client.listObjects(bucketName)
    var flag: Boolean = true
    var count=0
    while (flag) {
      val iterator: Iterator[_] = object_listing.getObjectSummaries.iterator()
      while (iterator.hasNext) {
        val summary: S3ObjectSummary = iterator.next().asInstanceOf[S3ObjectSummary]
        count+=1
      }

      flag=false
      println("Number of objects are: " + count)

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What dependencies are you using in build.sbt for these libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `AWSCredentialsProvider`:

```
 val provider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
   new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY,AWS_SECRET_KEY)
 )
```

and then use it to create the client:

```
 val client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
   .standard
   .withCredentials(provider)
   .withRegion("us-west-1") // or whatever  your region is
   .build
```

Comment: and if I want to delete folders inside certain bucket in S3 how may i do that?

Comment: There are no folders in S3, only keys. If you want to delete all objects with a given prefix, you have to list them all first, and then delete each one. 
You can read AWS SDK docs to get familiar with the API:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html